# How to use gsub twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to perform to search and replace activity

1. "{{content}}" => replace. (this to keep same type) regex gsub(/"{{(.*?)}}"/)
2. "hello {{content}}" => repalce (this to replace from string) regex gsub(/{{(.*?)}}/)

Method that i build is

```
def fill_in(template)   
      template.gsub(/\"\{\{(.*?)\}\}\"/) do
        "test"   
      end 
end
```

Tried **`template.gsub(/\"\{\{(.*?)\}\}\"/).gsub(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/) do`**   but this is giving
me error

> undefined method `gsub' for #<Enumerator:
> "{{user_name}}":gsub(/"{{(.*?)}}"/)>

first gsub is priority if it matches that pattern replace based on then if not check for second gsub

```
template.gsub(/\"\{\{(.*?)\}\}\"/) do
   # content will be replaced from the data object          
end.gsub(/\"\{\{(.*?)\}\}\"/) do
   # content will be replaced from the data object  
end
```

do body for both gsub is same, how to stop this repetition

Comment: What was the error? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew undefined method `gsub' for #<Enumerator: "{{user_name}}":gsub(/\"\{\{(.*?)\}\}\"/)>

Comment: Why don't you use a *replacement string* then? `gsub(/.../)` will return an enumerator, you need to add `'test'` as the replacement argument. `template.gsub(/\"\{\{(.*?)\}\}\"/, "test").gsub(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/, "test")`, see https://ideone.com/zAXUPD

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , i have to use do end as complex lookup needs to be there

Comment: Explain what you need in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew added

Comment: What about combining the two patterns into one? `/(")?\{\{(.*?)\}\}(?(1)"|)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it will be great if it can be done , getting this Conditionals are not supported in this regex dialec

Comment: In Ruby, regex library is Onigmo, it supports conditional constructs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i need help on this https://ideone.com/3AxiEe

Comment: Now, you made the question unclear. If you need help, update the question with an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why not just use 2 different statements/lines instead of chaining `gsub`s together?

Answer (score 1):

The [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with just a regex as a single argument to return an *Enumerator*, so you won't be able to chain the `gsub` in this way.

You can combine the two patterns into one:

```rb
/(")?\{\{(.*?)\}\}(?(1)"|)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8LKGQ2/1). Details:

- `(")?` - Capturing group 1 (optional):
- `\{\{` - a `{{` text
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (if you need to match line breaks, too, use `((?s:.*?))` instead, or simply add `/m` flag)
- `\}\}` - a `}}` string
- `(?(1)"|)` - a conditional construct: if Group 1 matched, match `"`, else, match an empty string.

In the code, you will need to check if Group 1 matched, and if so, implement one replacement logic, else, use another replacement logic. See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/vTxjgZ):

```rb
def fill_in(template)   
    template.gsub(/(")?\{\{(.*?)\}\}(?(1)"|)/) { 
        $~[1] ? "Replacement 1" : "Replacement 2" 
    }
end

p fill_in('"{{hello}}" and {{hello}}')
# => "Replacement 1 and Replacement 2"
```

Comment: can you check what wrong i am doing in this https://ideone.com/3AxiEe

Comment: @KunalVashist Not sure what you are doing, see [what the values are](https://ideone.com/xsiB32) in your code, debug and fix.

Comment: So thing is is "{{}}" this is replaced type can be changed 
and "as {{}}" in this case it will be string only, regex is not working in a case "{{test}} i am "

Comment: for "{{user_name}} is an {{user_name}}" i am getting [:"user_name}} is an {{user_name"]

Comment: $1 is also empty @Wiktor